# Page width in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want ot draw a line the full width of the page in SSRS.

If I could get the page width in (say) px, I could assign it as an expression to the line width. Is this possible? How? Or is there an alternative?

Comment: why doesn't setting the line length the same as the width of the report/body work? [just put it in cm/in]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do this, because a line get the start and end point positions. may be you can set this values to a big number and this solution solve your problem.

Comment: So you can't set an expression for start and end points? That's a shame. It makes fancy layouts impossible.